# Rendering HTML formatted mongo-documents

Tags: html, mongodb, meteor

So, here is a scenario.

I have one message box in my page. And I'm displaying message strings from the collection in that box.

```
Template.HomePage.Messages = function(){
   var  Messages = MessageCollection.find({raceId: Session.get('race_id')});
      if(Messages.count() > 0){
         return Messages;
      }
}
```

The collection contains bunch of messages as strings and simply rendered through `{{#each}}` block.

And the question is: How can I display the messages with HTML markup in it?

For eg. If the String is:

```
Hello <b> how are you? </b>
```

This should be displayed as:

Hello **how are you?**

Currently it displays the all the html tags in the strings. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `{{{value}}}` instead of `{{value}}`.